# Angular 5 cookie based authentication with PHP

Tags: php, authentication, cookies, angular5

I'm trying to setup a cookie based authentication between angular 5 and PHP 7. 
The login route do return a correct authentication cookie, but it is not stored on the browser. Then subsequent requests do not include this cookie, resulting in a 403 error.

My PHP session is initialized as such:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', 'my.domain.com');
session_name('domain_prod');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'my.domain.com', true, true);
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
```

On the front-end, I'm adding the following headers to each request:

```
{
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}),
    withCredentials: true
}
```

Locally it works well, even in PROD mode. The same back-end configuration also works well with angularJS.

Note that I enabled CORS locally because I'm working on a different port:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost:4200');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

I tried to enable it as well on my server, but to no avail.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: my.domain.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

I'm at a loss as to why the cookie isn't stored, probably a configuration issue, but I do not know where to look at.

Thanks for your help.